# Using aws STS to get temporary credentials: Where is the web identity token?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sts

My users login to my application through a microservice that connects to cognito (the request is proxied via API gateway)

They get a session token.

Once logged in, they need to put some files to S3.

I want to give them temporary credentials using STS but to call `sts.AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity` I need a web identity token.

How can I get a web identity token with a session token as input?

I wrote a temporary lambda (node) that returns STS credentials upon logging with a username and password:

```
const cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
const cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity();
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.initiateAuth(...) //AuthFlow: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH'
    cognitoidentity.getId(...)
        cognitoidentity.getCredentialsForIdentity(...)
```

There can be some time between the login and the file upload and I don't want the user to submit user/password each time. There's no AuthFlow accepting a session token either.

I'm guessing the API Gateway could return something useful but I didn't find anything in the docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few checks first:

- let cognito authenticated user to "masquerade" under an iam role, to do that we use [trust relationships](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-trust-and-permissions.html), for quick you can reuse the iam role that get assigned to your cognito identity pool.
- grant that iam role a policy to [access to s3 bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/understanding-amazon-cognito-authentication-part-3-roles-and-policies)

Once done:

Run `cognitoidentity.getCredentialsForIdentity(...)` again, it will go through sts first, thus you don't have to call sts assume role api. If successful, the response should have `AccessKeyId`, `SecretKey` and `SessionToken`. These are **expiry aws creds that have access to s3** and will be gone after an hour (unless set). Use them as normal session authentication.

```
creds = new SessionAWSCredentials(AccessKeyId, SecretKey, SessionToken);
s3Request = CreateAmazonS3Client(creds);
```